# Post-hoc using lsmeans in more than of factor resulted on identical values

Tags: r, lme4, posthoc

I am trying to run post-hoc comparison on a lmer model including more than one factor which do not interact. However, the output is identical between my between subject factor. Any idea why?

var1 is a within subject variable and var2 and var3 are between subject variables. Pred1 is a continuous variable. The model is running perfectly.

However, while I try to compute post-hoc analysis using lsmeans or emmeans, I have identical values. It does not happen when I write and run models with interactions, and if the present model is with a three-way interaction it works. However the model is not the best one, so I would avoid to do it.

Model:

```
model1 <- lmer(pred1~var1*var2 + var3 + (1|var4), data = mydata, REML = FALSE)
summary(model1)
anova(model1)
```

```
lsmeans, list(pairwise ~var1|var2|var3)
```

lsmeans results on:

```
var2 = 1, var3 = 0:
 contrast      estimate    SE  df t.ratio p.value
 var1a - Var1b    1.500 0.393 105 3.814   0.0002 

var2 = 2, var3 = 0:
 contrast      estimate    SE  df t.ratio p.value
 var1a - Var1b    0.323 0.301 105 1.074   0.2851 

var2 = 1, var3 = 1:
 contrast      estimate    SE  df t.ratio p.value
 var1a - Var1b    1.500 0.393 105 3.814   0.0002 

var2 = 2, var3 = 1:
 contrast      estimate    SE  df t.ratio p.value
 var1a - Var1b    0.323 0.301 105 1.074   0.2851
```

As you can see, the two last one are a replication in all values of the two first one.

Do you have any idea on how to fix it without including a three-ways interaction in my model? Or maybe a reason why it is normal that it is not running correctly?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The lsmeans summarize a model, and your model specifies an additive effect of x3. Since x3 doesn’t interact with other factors, the effects of the other factors are the same regardless of the level of x3. This is exactly what is shown in your results, and it is a consequence of the model you specified.

A reasonable summary of this model would be via the specs `pairwise ~ x1 | x2` and `pairwise ~ x3`.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, it makes sense. So, is there another way to get the difference between all my subgroups without using t-test? For example, if I would like to report the difference between var1a and var1b for each level of var2 in each level of var3? I mean, it there a way to calculate that?